# Make the Bootstrap Navbar Sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want to make a Navbar using Bootstrap then when you scroll down past 150 pixels the navbar has a background that is slightly transparent all the examples I have found for this on Stackoverflow haven't been what I need :/ I know how to add classes and so on with jQuery and when you scroll down pass a certain height but I want the Navbar to fadeOut and then fadeIn with a different class but I haven't found a way to do this.

I am grateful for any help :)

Thanks, 
Ste

Answer:
jQuery

```
$(window).on( "scroll", function() {
   $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled navbar-fixed-top', $(this).scrollTop() > 150);
});
```

CSS

```
nav.scrolled {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

nav {
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav id="secondNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive Slider</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navText">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ they have multiple fade in and fade out animations. Just drop in the css file and add the classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the fading with just css transitions all you need to do is use jquery toggleClass function when the window reaches 150px.

Try the following:

```
$(window).on( "scroll", function() {
   $('#secondNav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 150);
});
```

and the css

```
#secondNav.navbar-default{
  background: #000;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
#secondNav.scrolled {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

The transition property is what will give you the fade in and out and then you can change the background of the navbar-default to whatever you want it to be.  When it reaches 150px it will toggle the scrolled class and change the background.

Comment: Glad to help just to let you know it may be better to add the classes to the .navbar-default as with bootstrap that is what originally has the css for the background and such.  I will update the answer to reflect that

Comment: You can disregard my pevious comment as your code will work just fine the way that it is but I updated my answer to reflect the html that you posted as it wasn't there before.  You may use the updated answer if you like or not they are basically the same.  Glad I could help, happy coding.

Comment: That's fine I changed it to what you have as I understand where your coming from and it did mess up a little but none the less I found out why xD I just have one more question if maybe you could help. I have a scrollTop button on my page and when they press the button it takes them straight to the top the only problem is the navbar does this weird fadeOut fadeIn kind of glitch that makes it look untidy, just wondering if you know why or anything

Comment: Ah don't matter my friend I found a fix. Instead of scrollTop() > 150 just have it as 0 I think because of the way pixels work and so on a quick scroll to the top makes it fade in, fade out pretty quick so changing it to 0 fixed my problem I stated in the last comment

Comment: What code are you using to scroll to the top?     $('button').on("click", function(){
  $("body,html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
});    I have tested this in chrome, firefox, and IE and there is no glitches

Comment: Yep that's the code I use when jumping to the top, I wouldn't say it's a glitch it's just when it happens the Navbar does the transition twice. Neither mind I found an easy fix by changing the scroll hide to 0 instead of 170

Answer (score 1):

I have a difficult solution. You can create two `navbar`. second `nav` should be hidden. when you `scroll` more than `150px`, then it should be `fade in` with fixed position. Below my jQuery code is

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolled>149){
       $('#second_nav').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('#second_nav').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Below the code is first nav.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

And below the code is second nav.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="second_nav">
```

Check my live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/64s99gad/)

Comment: This one works just fine too, thanks for your help Sarower I appreciate it :)

Answer (score -2):

Are you using jQuery? if so, maybe something like this?

```
$('#div').click(() => {
    $('#div').fadeOut();


  $('#div')
  .css('background-color', 'green')
  .fadeIn();

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/53n2o76g/